# Python Tornado I/O Loop current() vs instance() method

Tags: python-2.7, asynchronous, tornado, python-multithreading

I have been looking through tornado documents.

While reading on IOLoop, there are contents on which It is saying like below.

> In general you should use IOLoop.current as the default when
>   constructing an asynchronous object, and use IOLoop.instance when you
>   mean to communicate to the main thread from a different one.

It makes sense that I have to use `instance()` method to communicate over multi-threads sharing one global `IOLoop` instance.

But What is `asynchronous object` in here and Why should I use `current()` in the case of `asynchronous object?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Asynchronous object" just means an object like `IOStream` or `HTTPServer` which has asynchronous methods.

You should **almost always** use `IOLoop.current()` instead of `IOLoop.instance()`. In most cases they are equivalent because you only have one thread and one `IOLoop`, but when they are different `current()` is usually what you want. The only time when `IOLoop.instance()` should be used is when A) you have multiple threads and B) a thread other than the IOLoop thread needs to call `add_callback` (which is the only way that another thread can interact with the IOLoop).

Comment: I don't understand you say when they are different ( threads? ) `current()` is usually what you want. But then in next line you say `IOLoop.instance(0` is needed when u have multiple threads.

Comment: I tried using `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_callback( callback=lambda : socketObject.send(simplejson.dumps(msg)))` from separate threads and `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().add_callback( callback=lambda : socketObject.send(simplejson.dumps(msg)))`, both work fine. Is there a performance difference btwn two?

Comment: `instance()` is still sometimes useful (prior to Tornado 6.0) - that's why it still exists. But most of the time `current()` is what you want. Performance should be the same.

Comment: So if I want multiple threads (ie program should handle concurrent API calls instead of queuing them all up) should I be using `instance()`? This project (not mine) is using instance() and is putting a `@tornado.gen.coroutine` decorator above its api call classes: https://github.com/mehmetkose/tornado-user-authentication-example/

Comment: No,the point of the asynchronous model is that you can have concurrency without threads. You just have to make sure that everything time-consuming happens in something that is `await`ed instead of being called directly on the main thread. (For IO, this means doing everything through async-based libraries. For CPU-bound tasks, use a ThreadPoolExecutor and `run_in_executor`)